# Content changes when using autolayout

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, ios7, autolayout

In xib table is having 1 rows
Dynamically as the app progresses in table from code there are 3 rows.
In table view I have button in cell on whole click I need to show one pop up view and set its frame according to cell frame
On the click I set frame of that pop up view
As soon as the pop up view's frame is set the view is seen as it is seen in xib
that is now instead of 3 rows there is only 1 row as in xib

These all happens when I set auto layout to true
If I set auto layout false there is no problem
 I am not writing code as there is no code except I set frame with CGRECT

Comment: Can you post some code or screenshots of what happens? It's hard to get that from the description.

Comment: please write down code you had written, this make your question clear and will make easy to understand your problem

Comment: I have edited question as the thing happens, only on setting frame, I have not written code, On button click I set frame, and if autolayout is true may be due to layout subview methods of view controller the interface changes. I am not understanding what to do. I want to use autolayout

Comment: If you want to use auto-layout then you must need to do more than just  set frame or add subview. for auto-layout you have to deal with constraints. for more detail study auto-layout and working with constraints

Comment: ya but these view has to be shown according to cell position dynamically, i.e. according to the row it is clicked, so can not set any constraint on these view and have to set its frame dynamically, the below views are using constraints and they are proper, thats why want to use autolayout for below views, as they are working properly

Comment: check this might help you https://github.com/Alex311/TableCellWithAutoLayout/

Answer (score 0):

got it

in viewDidLoad I wrote
self.tblTemp.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;

so now my table does not change frame.

In the scenario above I used autolayout in the view as I used the constraints for other controls, but I did not want to use for these particular table.
I did not use any constraints for table view, as I needed to change its frame dynamically.
so I put the above line

Previously table was automatically changing the frame to the one set in xib, on changing any particular frame(I need to show or hide pop up view on some cell button click, so I just set frame there)

I think here apple is translating my auto resizing constraints to auto layout ones. I am not still not sure how it is working. I read some where in apple guidelines about translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints, as actually by default it is YES.

If anyone finds useful